# How to convert UTF16 (emoji) to HTML Entity (hex) using java

Tags: java, html, jsp, emoji, emoticons

```
How to convert UTF16 (emoji) to HTML Entity (hex) using java


I have the string from DB like this "\uD83D\uDE02". 
I try to display this unicode emoji, it displays as ��. 
I search in google to convert UTF16 to Html hex code. But i didnt get any solution. Please help me
```

I will show this unicode to Emoji smily icon

Comment: check this library https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java also note, you need font with emoji support.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [emoji4j](https://github.com/kcthota/emoji4j) library for this.

For example:

```
String line = "Hi , i am fine \uD83D\uDE02 \uD83D\uDE02, how r u ?";

EmojiUtils.hexHtmlify(line); //Hi , i am fine &#x1f602; &#x1f602;, how r u ?
```

Comment: Its working fine above example but If the String is "&#55357;&#56833;", it throws an error, how it will handle ?

Comment: As of v4.0, the library only has support for processing decimal and hexadecimal html entities only. I just checked in the changes and released v5.0, which is capable of processing surrogate decimal entities. Refer the unit tests for more examples. Try out the new version and feel free to open an issue if you see any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Although the string appears to contain two Unicode characters, it's already one character encoded in UTF-16, that's how Java strings work. You can determine the actual UTF-16-decoded character code using the [`String.codePointAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt-int-) method. Here the character's code is 0x1F602, which is Unicode ['FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f602):

To write the character to HTML:

**OPTION 1:** generate the HTML escape entity

```
String str="\uD83D\uDE02";
FileWriter w=new FileWriter("c:\\temp\\emoji.html");
w.write("<html><body>");
w.write("&#x"+Long.toHexString(str.codePointAt(0))+";");
w.write("</body></html>");
w.close();
```

This yields

```
<html><body>&#x1f602;</body></html>
```

**OPTION 2:** use some Unicode-capable HTML encoding such as UTF-8

```
String str="\uD83D\uDE02";
OutputStreamWriter w=new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\emoji.html"),"UTF-8");
w.write("<html>\n<head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head>\n<body>");
w.write(str);
w.write("</body></html>");
w.close();
```

This yields

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>рџ‚</body></html>
```

which is the same happy face encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: My actual string is looks like " Hi , i am fine \uD83D\uDE02 \uD83D\uDE02, how r u ?". Its cobination of chat content with emoji icons

Comment: @chakri, to convert the whole string using OPTION 1, you will have to use a loop iterating over all *code points* (not *characters*) in the string. It will be a good idea to generate escape-entities only for characters >=128 and write characters <128 as they are. In OPTION 2 you just write the whole string to the stream and it is automatically converted to UTF-8.