# ReGex for avoid emoji - Unicode/ BigQuery

Tags: regex, unicode, emoji, google-bigquery

We receive a survey Web-hook data in Bigquery. The comment in local language is captured as unicode and special character. i already write function to convert the unicode to local language and do regex to avoid special characters.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DecodeUnicode(s STRING) AS (
(SELECT CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CAST(CONCAT('0x', x) AS INT64)))
FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(s, '\\u')) AS x
WHERE x != ''
)
);
WITH NPSDashboard_Webhook_Data1_copy AS (
SELECT
TRIM(Comment) Comment
FROM
`radiant-micron-790.Sharmila_Testing.NPSDashboard_Webhook_Data1_copy`
)
,
uchars AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
c,
DecodeUnicode(c) uchar
FROM NPSDashboard_Webhook_Data1_copy,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Comment, r'(\\u[abcdef0-9]{4})')) c
)

SELECT
Comment,
STRING_AGG(IFNULL(uchar, x), '' ORDER BY pos) Decoded
FROM (
SELECT
Comment,
pos,
SUBSTR(Comment,
SUM(CASE char WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 6 END)
  OVER(PARTITION BY Comment ORDER BY pos) - CASE char WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 5 
  END,
  CASE char WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 6 END) x,
  uchar
  FROM NPSDashboard_Webhook_Data1_copy,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Comment, r'(\\u[abcdef0-9]{4})|.')) char WITH OFFSET AS pos
  LEFT JOIN uchars u ON u.c = char
  )
  GROUP BY Comment
```

its return error:-

- Query Failed
- Error: Invalid codepoint 55357

i found that "\ud83c\udf38" its return error this is " Cherry Blossom" in  emoji return error. how to do regex or converter to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in pure SQL.

I suggest converting the UTF-16 Emojis to HTML Entities (hex) to store them in the DB. Most probably you need to utilize a programming language to do so:

Try it like this in .NET

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlEncode("\uD83D\uDE02"));
    }
}
```

Or you can use [emoji4j](https://github.com/kcthota/emoji4j) library for this in Java ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032302/how-to-convert-utf16-emoji-to-html-entity-hex-using-java)):

```
String line = "Hi , i am fine \uD83D\uDE02 \uD83D\uDE02, how r u ?";
EmojiUtils.hexHtmlify(line); //Hi , i am fine &#x1f602; &#x1f602;, how r u ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and [wrote up](https://sigpwned.com/2022/11/08/bigquery-regexp-for-matching-single-emoji/) the regex I ended up using to extract/replace emoji from strings in BigQuery:

```
(?:[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]|[\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}]|[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]|[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]|[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{24C2}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1FF}]{1,2}|[\x{1F170}\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}\x{1F17F}\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}]\x{FE0F}?|[\\x{0023}\x{002A}\x{0030}-\x{0039}]\x{FE0F}?\x{20E3}|[\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}-\x{21AA}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}\x{2B1C}\x{2B50}\x{2B55}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2934}\x{2935}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{3297}\x{3299}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F201}\x{1F202}\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}\x{1F251}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{203C}-\x{2049}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{00A9}-\x{00AE}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2122}\x{2139}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F004}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F0CF}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{231A}\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23E9}\x{23F3}\x{23F8}\x{23FA}]\x{FE0F}?)
```

The regex matches individual emoji, so you can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value, r"(?:[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]|[\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}]|[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]|[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]|[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{24C2}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1FF}]{1,2}|[\x{1F170}\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}\x{1F17F}\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}]\x{FE0F}?|[\\x{0023}\x{002A}\x{0030}-\x{0039}]\x{FE0F}?\x{20E3}|[\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}-\x{21AA}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}\x{2B1C}\x{2B50}\x{2B55}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2934}\x{2935}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{3297}\x{3299}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F201}\x{1F202}\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}\x{1F251}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{203C}-\x{2049}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{00A9}-\x{00AE}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2122}\x{2139}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F004}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F0CF}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{231A}\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23E9}\x{23F3}\x{23F8}\x{23FA}]\x{FE0F}?)")` to extract all individual emoji from a string.

You can also use `REGEXP_REPLACE(value, r"(?:[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]|[\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}]|[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]|[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]|[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{24C2}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1FF}]{1,2}|[\x{1F170}\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}\x{1F17F}\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}]\x{FE0F}?|[\\x{0023}\x{002A}\x{0030}-\x{0039}]\x{FE0F}?\x{20E3}|[\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}-\x{21AA}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}\x{2B1C}\x{2B50}\x{2B55}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2934}\x{2935}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{3297}\x{3299}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F201}\x{1F202}\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}\x{1F251}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{203C}-\x{2049}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{00A9}-\x{00AE}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2122}\x{2139}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F004}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F0CF}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{231A}\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23E9}\x{23F3}\x{23F8}\x{23FA}]\x{FE0F}?)", '')` to remove all emoji from a string.